Go SSH Failed with host key mistmach
Enviornment:
We execute command on ESX remotely using golang ssh with private key.
Error: SSH connection with go failed with below error, using lib https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: host key mismatch
What changed:
Upgraded our ESX version to 7.0.3, which upgrades openssh to 8.8. This version of ssh disabled RSA signature using SHA-1 algorithm.
Release: https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8
This release disables RSA signatures using the SHA-1 hash algorithm by default.
Another issue:
Golang ssh supports SHA1 by default on the version we were using. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/49952
What I tried:

Used updated golang version which supports other SHA-2.
As mentioned workaround by openssh and Broadcom i set below flags in ssh config of ESX which does not work. https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8 https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article?legacyId=88055.


HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

What works:

Checked the keys are correct in .ssh/known_hosts (client) and
authorized_keys (server) is same.
Tried generating public key from private key (ssh-keygen -y -e -f .ssh/id_rsa) which is exactly same as authorized_keys.
Manual ssh using id_rsa works fine.
Changing key from ssh-rsa to ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 works fine with go client.

Client ssh config:
hostkeyalgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
hostbasedkeytypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
kexalgorithms diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
casignaturealgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa

Server ssh config:
ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
hostkeyalgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
hostbasedalgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
kexalgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256

Server ssh logs(/var/log/auth.log):

2024-05-13T04:51:46.823Z sshd[2220706]: FIPS mode initialized
2024-05-13T04:51:46.304Z sshd[2220684]: Connection from 
port 41440
2024-05-13T04:51:46.313Z sshd[2220684]: Connection closed by  port 41440 [preauth]


ssh: host key mismatch usually means that the client's host key verification failed. You said you checked that the keys

in .ssh/known_hosts (client) and authorized_keys (server) is same.

but they should not be. Can you empty .ssh/known_hosts on the client and then ssh into the host? What shows up afterwards? Does it work then? Also, you need to be sure that the same hostname is used.
